# Is there a spherical joint equivalent to a 4 bar linkage?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, linkage

In a 4-bar linkage, all the joints are regarded as hinge joints. However, when I searched "spherical 4-bar linkage system", I didn't get a 4-bar system with spherical joints but instead a 4 bar system curved over the surface of a sphere.

Could someone show me an example of a 4-bar linkage system with straight rods that uses spherical joints? I want to understand the mathematics of the kinematic equations for one and I need a standard example. Is there a name for this?

Comment: If you put spherical joints in, there will be too many degrees of freedom for the constrained motion that 4-bar linkages are designed to provide. What are you hoping to use this for?

Comment: A car steering linkage is a simple example, if you include the independent vertical motion of the wheels relative to the car body when driving on an uneven surface.